# navsat_transform_node not publishing ? with Mavros

Tags: navigation, gps, ros-melodic, mavros, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I would like to use the robot_localization package to get back the missing TF transform from mavros topics (I didn't configure it during a rosbag record) on Melodic (from  src)
I'm using a rosbag with sim time.

My current configuration is : (I'm trying different setups)

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" clear_params="true">
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/navsat_transform_template.yaml" />

  <remap from="imu/data" to="mavros/imu/data"/>
  <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="mavros/global_position/local"/>
  <remap from="gps/fix" to="mavros/global_position/raw/fix"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

The yaml file

```
# Frequency of the main run loop
frequency: 3
transform_timeout: 0.1
delay: 0
magnetic_declination_radians: 0
yaw_offset: 0.0
zero_altitude: true
broadcast_utm_transform: true
broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false
publish_filtered_gps: false
use_odometry_yaw: false
wait_for_datum: true
datum: [XXX.716188, XX.213047, 0.0]
```

I'm using for this purpose but on another robot I will have to use it with ekf node (no mavros). So I would like to be sure to understand it. Mavros is already sending a odom topic but I would like to use only the gps and the imu.

For visualization, I'm also using mapviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345239/navsat_transform_node-not-publishing-?-with-mavros/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2020-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2020-02-27**:
I can provide on MP a rosbag

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2020-02-27**:
Seems that I cannot directly use the navsat_transform node without ekf one :
[link](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/377)

So I tried the ekf alone and it seems to do the job.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-04-27**:
Does that mean you've answered your question? If so, can you convert your comment to an answer and then select it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems that I cannot directly use the navsat_transform node without ekf one
So I tried the ekf alone and it seems to do the job.

---

Originally posted by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) with karma: 109 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0